# Is it bad practice to inject a value into a Spring controller?

Tags: spring

I have a Spring controller and there is a String parameter I want to inject into this controller. So I'm considering adding a new constructor to the controller which accepts the String as a parameter. Is this a bad practice since Spring controllers are singletons ?

Comment: What do you mean by "a String parameter"? A configuration property? Where does this parameter come from?

Comment: @JB Nizet yes this is a configuration property

Comment: Then I don't see why it would be a bad practice or cause any problem. You have a singleton controller, and want it configured.

Comment: No - that's fine practice. You can combine it with a property placeholder if you use e.g. XML config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject your String parameter instead:

```
@Value("${dropbox.access-token")
private String accessToken;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always model you configurations through classes (or even better records). Using `@Value` is just another form of field injection which is considered bad practice already, so instead of `@Value` you should do something along the lines of:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dropbox")
@ConstructorBinding
public final class DropboxConfiguration {
    private final String accessToken;

    public DropboxConfiguration(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = Objects.requireNonNull(accessToken);
    }
}
```

and then inject it as normal (of course through the constructor - not in a field). That way you get:

- Documentation of your configurations
- The ability to validate your config in a consistent manner
- Re-usability as well as re-factorability
- You can instantiate classes without firing up Spring (i.e. you avoid the huge downside of field-injection) - this can help immensly in testing